# Exclude Parent category ids from array of category id's

Tags: magento-1.8, category, array

Hi i'm having a product collection, i'm getting those categories by `$item->getCategoryIds();`

On  `print_r($categoryIds = $item->getCategoryIds());` i'm getting

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 26
)
Array
(
    [0] => 22
    [1] => 26
)
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 26
)
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 26
)
```

In these `category id 12 is parent for categories 26,22`

So is there any way to exclude parent category i.e 12 from array ? Smething like this i'm looking for

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 26
)
Array
(
    [0] => 22
    [1] => 26
)
Array
(
    [0] => 26
)
Array
(
    [0] => 26
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to not add the product to both categories, maybe make 12 a anchor category.

if you don't want this, you can load all the categories and check against `$category->getPath()` to filter parents...